# change into unicode language in run time in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode

I am quite familiar with VB.NET Windows form controls. What I wonder is, could I change the UI to another language at run-time? I would like my application to be usable in multiple languages.

I tried to do a search about it in Google, with no luck.
In Android, you can give different values in layout or resource folders.
So what I considered is that I have to call respective form when user chooses another language.

I know about changing "fonts" in environment setting.
Could you guide me which as to which articles I should read or processes I should follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of storing a culture name in the settings e.g. "en" or "en-US" for English or U.S. English.  Then, you can apply it using something like the following in your App.xaml.vb:

```
Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureString)
If culture IsNot Nothing Then
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
EndIf
```

(where `cultureString` is the string from your application settings)

There is also a `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` in `CultureInfo` that you may wish to set.

When you have resources, you can then add new resource files for different cultures that you wish to support.  For example, you might have your main resource strings in `resources.resx`, then you would have Chinese resource strings in `resources.zh-hans.resx`.